# when breeze child entity update parent entity state is not change

Tags: c#, knockout.js, breeze, single-page-application

knockout SPA

When I Add/Update child entity, parent entity state is not change.

following Scenario I have this is client side change tracking using breeze

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}

public class Department
{
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}
```

When I update 'Department' of 'Student', Student Entity state Remain 'Unchanged'.

How can i get Department Changes from 'Student' entity state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you change the navigation property `Department` you don't change the entity `Student` because what made the change in this is the foregeing key of the *Department*, so if you want to get the state, you need to know that is not  the entity state that was changed it was the relationship state that was changedd, so you can get the state of the `ObjectContext` like this:

To get the entries use this:

```
var objCtx = ((IObjectContextAdapter)ctx).ObjectContext;
//In your case use the EntityState.Modified
var objentr = objCtx.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified);
```

To change:

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.
              ChangeRelationshipState(student, oldDepartment,
                                      c => c.Department, EntityState.Modified);
```

### Update after explanation about the question:

So given that what I told about the navigation property `Department` was true to *Breeze* too, so see this section in the documentation [Navigations properties - EntityState and PropertyChanged events after setting](http://breeze.github.io/doc-js/navigation-properties.html#entitystate-and-propertychanged-events-after-setting).

Comment: Thanks, Joel I am talking about client side not on server side.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just add the DepartmentID property to the Student? When the Department is updated the DepartmentID will change as well and the EntityState will update.